# Failure running "Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use automatic migration and have no code migrations defined. I want to emit a full DDL so we can set up the DB without running the application, and so it can be reviewed as acceptable against our internal standards.

This is what happens:

> PM> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0 No pending explicit
>   migrations. Applying automatic migration:
>   201607151128156_AutomaticMigration. Automatic migrations that affect
>   the location of the migrations history system table (**such as default
>   schema changes**) are not supported. Please use code-based migrations
>   for operations that affect the location of the migrations history
>   system table.
>   PM>

I have DbContext code like this which would seem to explain the issue:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //this is the schema to use
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("abc"); //OH NOES!
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(x => x.HasKey("name"));
```

So I have to manually add a migration for this? I don't understand code migration at all which is why I'm using automatic migration... what do I actually need to do so I can reliably dump out my entire DLL?

Comment: I wondered if I can exclude migrations history system table from default schema? Also, I can just add the schema as a prefix to my table-names rather than set a schema explicitly